# What styling do I need to make a web page a printable A4 page for a report?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, report

The topic says much of my question. I have given up on the chaotic and out-of-date reporting 'solutions' and will code my own, as Razor views, for now, for simple reports.

I would just like to know how to use CSS to achieve the same styling on a printed page as would be on a page printed from a normal reporting solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to style some elements only for print you are looking for the media rule `print`

```
@media print {
     /* CSS for print goes here */
}
```

But if you are looking for a big customization like show page 1 of 10, add somethings to the bottom of the page and another things, you can't do that because the browser don't let you. You should being use a PDF, so you can change whatever you want and generate it for print.

Comment: I'm actually just tying to avoid using a reporting engine, and render tables on pages styled for A4 paper so they can easily be printed.

Comment: But what problem are you getting to achieve this? did you tried just add a table and didn't work well ?

Comment: No. Print is different. That is why so many good web designers use separate style-sheets for print.